# What exactly represent a data-reveal-id attribute in html? and what is the difference with a classic id attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I am not so into HTML or HTML5 and I have the following question.

On a page that I am working on I have a map that has clickable regions implemented on a background image using the  html tag, something like this:

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">

    <area data-reveal-id="UM" shape="poly" data-nome-regione="Umbria"
                            coords="135,167,138,151,143,141,154,148,155,159,165,167,146,178" 
                            alt="Umbria" 
                            onmouseover="RollMapOn('umbria')" onmouseout="RollMapOff()" onclick="caricaDettaglioRegione(this)" />

    ....................................................................

    ....................................................................
</map>
```

My question is: why uniquely identify an area using the **data-reveal-id** attribute and not a standard **id** attribute? What is the difference? What exactly is a **data-reveal-id** attribute?

Comment: It depends totally on what your JS/CSS layer is expecting. There is no inheritant difference.

Comment: data-reveal-id is an attribute like data-test or data-test-id, and apparently he used be jquery modal reveal plugin [reference](https://changelog.com/reveal-jquery-modal-for-html5-and-data-attributes/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An [`id` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) uniquely identifies an element in a document. It has a number of restrictions on what values it can have, defined by HTML, including the requirement for uniqueness.

[`data-*` attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) are custom extensions primarily designed for JavaScript specific to a page to manipulate. The purpose (and allowed values) of any given `data-*` attribute are defined by the author of the page and is not standardised.